# Project could not Start

Tags: java, android, eclipse

**When i create new project using Eclipse and its placed after my other created project its not start display error.  and if its placed on start its start normally. see the image.[image: mention both project]**

**

I ask because I am not very familiar with Java and am currently converting some Java code to C# code and this one is giving me some trouble. I tried to restart Eclipse and computer. Thanks in advance.

**

Comment: Means you have error in your code..Try to debug it..Say where you are getting error i will help to solve ..

Comment: What its not clear for me..

Comment: no one error in code. its a new project. created recently

Comment: Post your code....Also check for java build path for any lib missing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps

1. right clcik on your project
2. go to properties
3. go to java build path
4. go to libraries tab
5. remove all the lib files from there (android dependency and android privet libraries) except android version lib
6. click ok
7. clean and build your project
8. run now

Comment: Good :-) but i am confused. those files i was removed that's are no need in future.

Comment: no there is no need of that. The error is because of ambiguity or duplicacy of those files only

Answer (score 1):

Check your **android:targetSdkVersion** in AndroidManifest.xml matches

```
 target=android-<value> in project.properties
```

If these two values are not equal, set your build tools version 19.0.0 will solved the BufferOverflowException

Answer (score 0):

Added this Line in your android "`project.properties`" file

```
sdk.buildtools=18.1.1
```

Thanks